# Select function-based index data as rows in a query?

Tags: oracle, index, select

I'm trying to learn about indexes in Oracle 18c.

As a novice, it's occurred to me that it might be interesting to view the actual data that's in a function-based index:

```
create index sidewalk_endpoint_list_idx on my_owner.sidewalks(my_owner.endpoint_list(shape),objectid);
```

Is there a way to SELECT an index's data in a query?

Fake example:

```
select
    *
from
    sidewalk_endpoint_list_idx
```

That might be a silly question. Maybe indexes aren't stored in tables. But I thought it was worth asking, just so I can learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, but you can select it from the table:

```
select my_owner.endpoint_list(shape),objectid,rowid
  from my_owner.sidewalks;
```